# Execute JavaScript before page loads in PhantomJS driven by Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I need to execute some javascript before the page page loads(= before the javascript on the page is executed)

Is that possible via ghostdriver?
using phantomjsdriver 1.2.1 for java, phantomjs 2.0

Comment: Can you edit the html prior to loading the page? You could add a `<script>` block before the other `<script>` blocks on the page

Comment: Thats the question. I have no idea how to do that with phantomjsdriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

PhantomJS is effectively a browser.  You cannot edit a webpage in a browser before the browser has loaded it.

Don't bother trying to disable JavaScript in PhatomJS either because then you won't be able to use JavaScript to inject the JavaScript you need before enabling JavaScript.